# reference mdf from different project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, project

I have solution with two projects.

1. ASP.NET MVC3
2. Class library

In class library I have mdf database and all the classes for BLL and DAL.

How can I create reference to this database from MVC project or how can I tell class library to use connection string and mdf from MVC project App_Data folder?

Comment: Best solution: **attach** it to a server instance and reference it from both projects using that logical database name (instead of referencing the file with its physical path). If your MVC project references the class library DLL, then the config settings from the MVC `web.config` are also available in the DLL for your use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Best way I can see is to reference class library in mvc project.

   1. In your class library you can use `ConfigurationManager` class to read connection string and app settings which will automatically use web.config of website.
   2. Next is, in model folder, just create FACADE class(s) in order to call your BAL in class library. If you like, you can skip this step and directly create object of class in BAL and use it.

For samples, you can see example of mvc store front and other examples on [codeplex](http://mvcsamples.codeplex.com/).
I hope this will help.

Thanks
Prashant